# Source Control on the IBM i (iSeries)

Tags: version-control, ibm-midrange, rpgle

On the web side we are working on getting source control. Now, I want to see what can be done for the iSeries side. What is your favorite source control application for iSeries and why? I am looking for low-cost if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two most common source control packages for the iSeries are [Turnover](http://www.softlanding.com/turnover/index.htm) and [Aldon](http://www.aldon.com/products/lmi/). Neither are low cost but integrate well with the iSeries.

I prefer **Turnover**.  It flawlessly handles production installs to both a local and remote iSeries.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget about **MKS Implementer** ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the **WebSphere Development Studio** or **Rational** from a PC then any source control system that will play nicely with that is an option if you don't want to shell out for the native iSeries one.

Comment: But if you work with RSE directly and not through a project, you can't upload that to subversion.

Answer (score 1):

We use **Aldon** for our COBOL, CL, DDS code and it does a really good job. I don't know about the cost of it. There's a plug-in for the WebSphere Development Studio. Just about any source control option could handle archiving/versioning the source code, but Aldon excels at handling the compilation and deployment from dev to QA to production environments. It can keep different library lists for each, for example, and change them dynamically for compiling in different environments. It will even push code to other LPARs, if your dev and prod environments are not on the same LPAR.